# how to use caret ^ in expect statement

Tags: shell, expect

I want to use `^` in an expect script just like in the shell: `grep '^god'`.
Running:

```sh
echo -e "abc god 1st line\ngod 2nd line" | grep ^god
```

Returns:

```
god 2nd line
```

But `^` seems not to work when run in the following `expect` script:

```
spawn myscript
expect "^god" {puts "catch line start with god"}
```

Comment: Do you expect a *literal* caret, or do you expect that to be used as a beginning-of-line sigil? It would be helpful to make your example standalone (including within it the shortest possible code that generates the input you expect to be matched, as well as the code that should match it); that way, answers to questions about meaning can be inferred from the code, and people with answers can test them -- and the "reproducible" branch of the [mre] definition is satisfied.

Comment: I expect that to be used as a beginning-of-line sigil. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In expect, `^` matches the beginning of the buffer, which may not necessarily be the beginning of a line. (Similarly, `$` matches the end of the buffer). For example,

```
log_user 0
spawn -noecho printf {a\nb\nc\n}
expect  "^a" {puts ok}
```

will work, because `a` is the first character output. However, matching for `"^b"` will not work. Instead you would need to match for newline, eg:

```
expect "\nb" {puts ok2}
```

Note that these are *glob* patterns; you can add the `-gl` prefix to be explicit. `^` and `$` act the same in globs and regexps (`-re` prefix). You can use the `-ex` prefix to your pattern to instead match exactly for the caret character.

Comment: Note that whether `echo 'a\nb\nc'` in bash prints literal newlines or two-character `\n` sequences depends on which options it was compiled with, and active runtime flags (which themselves can be configured by environment variables, or with the `shopt` and `set -o` flags). Sometimes it'll only transform `\n`s to newlines when given `-e` (whereas at other times, `echo -e` just makes `-e` part of the output). To ensure consistent behavior, it's much better to use `printf` instead of `echo`.

Comment: Please make it clear that `^` and `$` is special only for `-gl` (the default) and `-re`, not for `-ex`.

Answer (score 1):

The caret is a *regular expression* metacharacter, so you need to tell the `expect` command that the pattern is a regex:

```
expect -re "^god" ...
```

However, that will only match at the very start of the command output.

The [Tcl regular expression syntax](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm) does provide the solution: newline sensitive matching:

```
expect -re {(?n)^god} {puts "found a diety"}
# ..........^^^^
```

With that addition, the caret will indeed match at the beginning of any newline-separated line.

Demo:

```sh
$ cat ./myscript
#!/bin/sh
printf "%s\n" foo bar god baz

$ expect -c '
  spawn -noecho ./myscript
  log_user 0
  expect {
    -re {(?n)^god} {puts "got a diety"; exp_continue}
    eof
  }
'
got a diety
```

Comment: In expect, `^` and `$` can be used for globs too.

Comment: I doubt it. Have a reference for that? The expect manual states that glob patterns "are specified as with Tcl's [`string match`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M35) command.

Comment: There are probably several versions of expect. `man expect` for me says, after providing an example using globs and regexps: *Both  types  of  patterns are "unanchored"....Use ^ to match the beginning of a  string,...*. And the example I posted works with a glob `^a`.

Comment: Ah yes, that is true. Thanks for the correction. Note the caveat: "However, because expect is not line oriented, these  characters  match  the
             beginning and end of the data (as opposed to lines) currently in the expect matching buffer."